# How to install jobb.bat tool android

Tags: android

I have my apk size upto 50mb so for this i am using expansion apk . on searching i came to know that there are different files which can be used as expansion files like zip and pdf etc. I am trying to put my data in .obb files but i don't know how to create these files and put the data in these file
sHow to install jobb.bat tool. my cmd is not recognizing jobb command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search on it i found that jobb.bat is available in SDK 21.0. As it given in SDK 21.0 for expension files. So after downloading and installing SDK 21.0 jobb command can be recognized on cmd.